# Haskell List Reversal Error

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'm writing a list reversal program for haskell.

I've got the idea for the list reversal and that has lead to the following code:

```
myreverse list1
 | list1 == []    = list1
 | otherwise      = (myreverse(tail list1)):(head list1)
```

Unfortunately the above code results in the following error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = [[a]]
 Expected type: [[a]]
 Inferred type: a
 In the second argument of '(:)', namely '(head list1)'
 In the expression: (myreverse(tail list1)):(head list1)
```

PS: I get the same sort of error when I run it on a snippet that I wrote called mylast coded below:

```
mylast list
 | list == []      = []
 | otherwise       = mylast_helper(head list1)(tail list1)

mylast_helper item list2
 | list2 == []     = item
 | otherwise       = mylast_helper(head list2)(tail list2)
```

Error occurs at the otherwise case of the recursive helper.

EDIT: Thanks for all the input, I guess I forgot to mention that the constraints of the question forbid the use of the ++ operator. I'll keep that in mind for future questions I create.

Cheers,
-Zigu

Answer (score 4):

You are using the function

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

with ill-typed arguments:

```
myReverse (tail list1) :: [a]
head list1 :: a
```

In your function, the list *list1* must have type *a*. Hence the second argument, *head list1*, must have type *[a]*. GHC is warning you that it cannot construct the type you have specified for it. The head of a list is structurally smaller than the tail of a list, but you are telling it that the head of a list has type *[a]*, yet the tail of a list has type *a*.

If you stare closely at your types, however, you will notice that you can *append* the head of *list1* to the recursive call to *myreverse* using *(++)*:

```
myReverse xs = case (null xs) of
               True  -> xs
               False -> myReverse (tail xs) ++ [head xs]
```

Here,

```
[head xs] :: [a]
myReverse (tail xs) :: [a]
```

which aligns with the type of *append*:

`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`

There are much better ways to implement *reverse*, however. The Prelude defines *reverse* as a left fold (. Another version of *reverse* can be implemented using a right fold, and is very similar to your *myReverse* function:

```
reverse xs = foldr (\x xs -> xs ++ [x]) [] xs
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of cons (`:`) is `a -> [a] -> [a]` - in other words, you give it an element and then a list and it puts the element at the start of the list.  In your last line, you're doing the reverse - list first and then an element.  To fix it up, change the `:` to the list concat operator `++`:

```
myreverse list1
  | list1 == [] = list1
  | otherwise   = (myreverse (tail list1)) ++ [head list1]
```

(To try and translate the error, it's saying "OK, the first argument to `:` you've given me is a list, therefore the second argument needs to be a list of elements of that same type, so a list of lists...BUT...you've given me an argument which is the type of an element of the list, so I need some type that is the same as a list of lists of that type, which I can't do.  Bang!")

Comment: Also this would run in O(n^2) time if it compiled

Comment: @yatima that was a typo, fixed, thanks for pointing it out.  @pelotom looking at the question and trying to gauge the asker's ability, I would argue that although it might not be efficient, it is appropriate...

Comment: @Jon fair enough, just thought I'd point it out. The use of `list1 == []` is more problematic... that unnecessarily imposes an `Eq` type class constraint on the function... I'd suggest changing it to `null list1`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what this error was. @pelotom: how would that comparison look like? list1 == null?

Comment: @Zigu replace that line with `  | null list1 = []`

Answer (score 3):

First off, try adding a signature to each of your functions; this will help the compiler know what you're trying to do and give you better error messages earlier on. A signature would look like this, for example: `mylast :: [a] -> a`. Then, instead of using guards (`|`), define your function through a series of equations, using pattern matching:

```
mylast :: [a] -> a
mylast (x:[]) = x
mylast (_:t) = mylast t
```

In GHCi, you can look at the type of something using `:t` *term*. That's the best general advice I can give... look carefully at the types and make sure they make sense for how you're using them.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up working on this question more and answering it myself.
Thanks a lot for the feedback. It pushed me along the right direction.

```
myreverse list1
 | list1 == []  = list1
 | otherwise    = myreverse_h(list1)([])

myreverse_h list1 list2
 | list1 == []  = list2
 | otherwise    = myreverse_h(tail list1)((head list1):list2)
```

Any comments on better code though? I don't think its as efficient as it could be...

Comment: That is pretty much how it is implemented in Prelude. Style-wise, you could use pattern-matching to split the head from the tail of lists, instead of using head and tail everywhere. Also, put space between the arguments of functions: `myreverse_h list1 []` looks much better than no whitespace and parentheses everywhere.